# Having you having eaten

Tags: sentence-construction

> - I won't listen without having you having eaten the apple.
> - I won't listen without having you ate the apple.

Are these sentences grammatically correct? Or is it rather awkward that the below having-you part should be completely revised?  *Having eaten* and**ate* are supposed to mean completed speech.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain more about the sense you want to get across.

Answer (score 1):

"I won't listen until you have eaten the apple" or "I won't listen unless you eat the apple" would be the natural ways of putting this in English. You could also say "I won't listen without having you eat the apple", but that sounds less natural, and also means that the listening would start while the apple was being eaten, not when it has been eaten